# LINQ EntitySets Filtering

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have recently added a new column to my table Cars to denote if the record is SOLD or not. I then propagated this change to my dbml.

However in my MVC controller I find myself writing `Dealer.Cars.Where(x=>x.Status != 'SOLD')` everywhere to filter out 'SOLD' records.

Is there a better or more centralized place to do this filtering?

I have read some suggestions but none of them are really suitable as I cannot change the results of the original .Cars referenced objects.

Comment: check repository pattern for a start with unit of work

Comment: You should wrap your Cars table  in a data access layer and remove this logic from your controller.

Comment: I already have repositories and a DAL. What your suggesting is using something like DealerRepo.GetAvailableCars(Dealer d);

Answer (score 0):

The feature to look into is Entity Framework Interceptor introduced in EF6

Check here 
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/soft-deleting-entities-cleanly-using-entity-framework-6-interceptors.html

There is also a video about it from rowan miller at teched 2014

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B417#fbid=

Answer (score 0):

No suitable answers above so I created a partial class for the entity and added a new Property that only returned filtered objects.